# Please help me work this script in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

```
<script>
$('#mbx').vTicker({
speed:500,
pause:5000,
animation:'false',
mousePause:true,
showItems:1,
});
</script>
```

i am using this very simple ticking script, my problem is that its working fine in all browsers except the most dreadful browser ie7, which obviously can't be ignored as well. when debugging its showing

Expected identifier, string or number
which is the first character `$('#mbx').vTicker({` here, now as is well known that ie7 gets confused with commas, that i also removed but it did not work and stopped working then in other browsers also, now can somebody help me find a solution of this problem proving for me really unbeatable.

Comment: it will definitely not work in IE7 with that comma after `showItems:1`, just saying...

Comment: remove the last comma after showtimes

Comment: Just to clarify you already tried to remove the trailing comma after `showItems:1,`

Comment: maybe `vTicker` is the realy issue?

Comment: @Jrod i don't see how this would've caused it to stop working on other browsers though. Could he possibly removed too many commas? :P

Comment: @GNi33 I am not suggesting it would have just trying to clarify what he already attempted.

Comment: ok removed it again, ie7 now stopped giving me any problem but got the ticker disappeared completely no css thing is effecting it to work again, don't know what could be else to make it work, anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesnt like objects with a trailing comma. Remove the comma after `showItems:1`.

Comment: finally it worked thanx, however its still a mystery for me how it suddenly started working while earlier it was not....